# Frenet Frame along a curve and Riemannian Curvature on $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curves, frenet-frame

I would appreciate some help showing the following statement.

Let $\omega: [0,1] \rightarrow S^2$ be a smooth curve with velocity vector $V = \omega'$, speed $v = |V|$ and Frenet frame $\{T,N\}$.

> Then for all vector fields $W: S^2 \rightarrow TS^2$ along the curve $\omega$ we have:
>
> $$R(W,V)V = v^2 \langle W , N \rangle N  $$

where $R$ is the Riemannian curvature tensor on $S^2$.

If $\omega$ were arc-length parametrized / unit-length, I suppose the terms $v^2$ could join the left side because of the normalization of $N = \frac{|T'|}{T'}$, but this isn't the case here.

Comment: No, the $v^2$ is there because $V=vT$.  What definition of the Frenet frame are they using? We're not thinking of $S^2\subset\Bbb R^3$ and of the Frenet frame of a curve in $\Bbb R^3$, I presume?

Comment: @TedShifrin I think they are but I’m not entirely sure. If it helps: Later calculations are made representing the vectorfield $W$ (as above) in terms of $W = fT + gN$. Furthermore for $\gamma $ with $\gamma‘ = \omega$ they get the Frenet Frame $\{T_\gamma, N_\gamma, B_\gamma \}$ such that $T_\gamma = \omega, N_\gamma = T, B_\gamma$ as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think the authors' use of the term Frenet frame is a bit misleading — I personally would call this a Darboux frame. Regardless, by $N$ they mean the normalized covariant derivative of $T$.

As I already commented, it suffices to show that $R(W,T)T = \langle W,N\rangle N$ (since $V = vT$).  Note that $R(T,T)T = 0$, so, writing $W=aT+bN$, we have $R(W,T)T = bR(N,T)T \overset{(*)}{=} bN = \langle W,N\rangle N$, as required. The equality (*) follows from the fact that the sphere has constant sectional curvature $1$.